# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found (NOT caused by the common cause for this error)

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am trying to use a library that uses JNI.

I've tried the sample app provided by the developers and it works. So I know it's not a bug in the library.

I assume I'm doing something wrong in the process of importing the library:

- copy the .so file into my libs folder (its called libjniRTSP.so)
- copy the the jniRTSP.java (summarized below) into my project:

  ```
  public class jniRTSP {

  private volatile static jniRTSP libRTSP = null;

  public static jniRTSP getInstance() {
      if(null == libRTSP) {
          synchronized(jniRTSP.class) {
              if(null == libRTSP) {
                  libRTSP = new jniRTSP();
                  libRTSP.InitProductList();

                  // DEBUG
                  libRTSP.SetDebugView(1);
              }
          }
      }
      return libRTSP;
  }

  static {
      try {
          System.loadLibrary("jniRTSP");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  public native int       GetBrandEnableRecorder();
  public native int       GetBrandEnableLocal();
  public native int       GetBrandEnableRemote();
  ...
  ```
- then in my onCreate() I try to call one of the methods:

  ```
  jniRTSP.getInstance().Init(.....)
  ```

  Which returns the error:

  > UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found com.myuniquepackage.jniRTSP.InitProductList:()I

UPDATE (FIX): instead of just copying the jniRTSP java file, I copied the whole package that contained it, keeping the same package name. I'm not sure if this fixed it because the package name was the issue, or if because it needed one of the other java files that were in that package. Although I'm pretty sure if it was a missing file, it would complain at compile time.

Comment: Is the call to `loadLibrary` actually succeeding? Also, are you sure that the jniRTSP methods are using the .NET capitalization convention instead of having a lowercase first letter?

Comment: There are only two 'common ones': library not found and method not found, and this is one of them.

Comment: @chrylis Yep it will be or he'd get an "UnsatisfiedLinkError cannot find library 'jniRTSP'" error before this one.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I'd never noticed that was an `Error`, not an `Exception`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly certain the package declarations have to be the same inside the C code as the Java code.

So the class jniRTSP should be in the com.myuniquepackage package in Java and have the native method InitProductList declared and the C code should have method declared as Java_com_myuniquepackage_jniRTSP_InitProductList

By moving the class you are probably breaking the link, change the package declaration in Java to match the demo project and see if it works, if it does you can change it back and then change it in the C code which is a bit more time consuming but easy enough.

Comment: No I just copied the whole jniRTSP.java file.

Comment: Also I don't think I have access to the C code, its packaged in the .so

Comment: Are the package declarations the same in each project? Depending how you copied the code they may have been automatically changed.